# how to print array of chars with its pointer?

Tags: c++, c-strings

I'm trying to do this :

```
void print(char *string){

int i = 0;

do{

    cout << string[i];
    i++;

} while (string[i] != '/0');
```

}

But on the output I have some weird results. How can I make this work. Am just trying to print out array of chars with a pointer to a 1st in line. TY

Answer (score 1):

Your null character literal is wrong; you need backslash: `'\0'`.

Comment: wow..can't believe that I didn't check that before posting.Lesson learned. Thank you sir !